# House Has Apron - Sump Pump Goes Out Window - Proper Drain In Wrong Place Still Better?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, sump

So my house has a concrete apron, about 20" or so off the house, and then grass.

The current sump discharge is out a hole in a plexiglass window.

I was going to lay a proper 4" SD pipe out to a drywell for both the SP discharge and the downspout...

But the "stack"/drain would be sticking out from the house to avoid drilling into the concrete apron. The stack would be on the back corner of the house, through the rim-joist at the first joist space/bay. I'd likely run the piping down the remaining foot or so of the foundation and kick it out to the stack 20" or so away from the house.

In my head this seems really weird and feels like it would look inappropriate... But I also feel like this is a hell of a lot better than leaving it the way it is.

Should I concern myself with the fact that this pipe would be 20"-ish off of the house into the lawn, or is this just the best option without drilling the concrete apron?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to
put a planter or something like that next to it, or over it, so (a) nobody will notice it, and (b) it won't be a trip hazard.

Comment: Yep, plants, or a short fence kind of thing.  Maybe even a rock garden or similar.